# passing parameters to native reduce script of ElasticSearch facet script

Tags: mapreduce, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use [elasticsearch facet script](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-facet-script), but when I get to the reduce phase's NativeScriptFactory the passed map parameter is empty. 
Here's my query:

```
    "facets": {
    "myFacet": {
        "script": {
            "lang": "native",
            "map_script": "MyMap",            
            "reduce_script": "MyReduce",            
            "params" : {
                "facet" : {}
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the default reducer, I get this response:

```
   "facets": {
        "myFacet": {
            "_type": "script",
            "facet": [
                {
                    "222790": 7,
                    "762984": 7
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

My map script looks like this:

```
public class MyMapScript extends AbstractSearchScript {

    private Map<String, Double> _myScores;

    public MyMapScript(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {

        _myScores = (Map<String, Double>) stringObjectMap.get("facet");
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        ScriptDocValues.NumericLong tags = (ScriptDocValues.NumericLong) doc().get("tags");
        for (Long t : tags.getValues()){
            Double score = 7.0;
            _myScores.put(t.toString(), score);
        }

        return _myScores;
    }
}
```

and the reduce script factory, which gets an empty map as a parameter:

```
public class MyReduceScriptFactory implements NativeScriptFactory {
    @Override
    public ExecutableScript newScript(@Nullable Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
        return new MyReduceScript(stringObjectMap);
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to get the mapper's output to the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was fixed at [latest version](https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-facet-script/commit/147d602525c9cf7b8a97389b479765958b8f9fb5), I was using an older one.